# How to Update data item in RecyclerView without notifyDataChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have download function on my app. I display downloading items in RecyclerView.
I used `notifyDataChanged` for update downloading progress but it's not good. The item has changed data is flashing when use `notifyDataChanged` for update data changed.

Is there any suggestion for update data changed of item in recyclerview without `notifyDataChanged`?

Comment: `notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: `notifyItemChanged` is flashing item in recyclerview

Comment: you can use `onActivityResult` for this